# Zend - Move file from application folder

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to create an Excel spreadsheat in a Zend Framework project.

The spreadsheat is created in my controller, and there doesn't seem to be a parameter in the save-function of the PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 class to save the file elsewhere.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think I can make a file that is stored in the application folder available for download since only the files in the public_html folder are accesible?

How can I move the file from the /application/admin/controllers folder to e.g. the /public_html/files folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call save on the excel object, give the path there with filename

or can also store path in a variable and use.

```
$object->save('/path/to/777/dir/file.xls');
```

You must have access to write in that folder.

Comment: I thought the parameter was just to change the file's name. Thank you.